Spring Framework 5 unit testing with MockMvc: how can I apply a SecurityFilterChain?
Here is my unit test code, which works as expected:

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SecurityFilterChainTest {

    @Inject
    SecurityFilterChain adminConsoleFilterChain;

    MockMvc api;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        api = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AdminController())
                // .apply(springSecurity(adminConsoleFilterChain.getFilters().get(0)))
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenUrlIs_x_then_is3xxRedirection() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/x"))
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/admin/"));
    }


I would like to add the code which is commented out. But how do I add the adminConsoleFilterChain which is declared as this?
@Bean
    @Order(SecurityConfigOrder.ADMIN_CONSOLE)
    public SecurityFilterChain adminConsoleFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


Instantiation of this bean requires a HttpSecurity instance. How would I get or inject one?

Found a solution:
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/master-context.xml", "/test-context.xml"})
public class SecurityFilterChainTest {

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("springSecurityFilterChain")
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    MockMvc api;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        api = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AdminController())
                .apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
                .build();
    }


